# ErrorException in UrlGenerationException.php line 17 laravel 5.4

Tags: php, routes, anchor, laravel-5.3

When i click my anchor tag i keep getting this error

> Missing required parameters for [Route: voyager.users.getprofile]
>   [URI: admin/users/{users}/{id}/getprofile]. (View:
>   /var/www/html/testadmin/vendor/tcg/voyager/resources/views/widget.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   /var/www/html/testadmin/vendor/tcg/voyager/resources/views/widget.blade.php))

I have an anchor tag

```
<li><a href="{{ route('voyager.users.getprofile', $id) }}">Profile</a></li>
```

My route:

```
Route::group([
            'as'     => 'users.',
            'prefix' => 'users/{users}',
        ], function () use ($namespacePrefix) {

                 Route::get('{id}/getprofile', ['uses' => $namespacePrefix.'Users@getprofile', 'as' => 'getprofile']);




        });
```

function:

```
public function getprofile()
    {
        echo 'hii';exit;
    }
```

I don't know why this happens.any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$id`'s value become `users`'s value in `'prefix' => 'users/{users}',`

Either you need to provide `users` value of remove it

```
'prefix' => 'users/',
```

So that `$id`'s value goes to `id` parameter.

Comment: -Thanks .answer is perfect but if a remove this prefix it'll affect other tags.

Comment: so you need to provide user's value as well.